# Use cell's color as condition in if statement (function)

Tags: excel, function, vba

I am trying to get a cell to perform a function based on the hilight color of a cell.

Here is the function I currently have:

```
=IF(A6.Interior.ColorIndex=6,IF(ROUNDDOWN(IF(M6<3,0,IF(M6<5,1,IF(M6<10,3,(M6/5)+2))),0)=0,0,ROUNDDOWN(IF(M6<3,0,IF(M6<5,1,IF(M6<10,2,(M6/5)+2))),0)),IF(ROUNDDOWN(IF(M6<7,0,IF(M6<10,1,M6/5)),0)=0,0,ROUNDDOWN(IF(M6<7,0,IF(M6<10,1,M6/5)),0)))
```

Just so you don't have to read through all of that, here's a more simple example

```
=IF(A6.Interior.ColorIndex=6,"True","False")
```

All that his is returning is #NAME? . Is there any way that I can do this as a function in a cell or is VBA absolutely required?

Thanks,

Jordan

Comment: Not to my knowledge, I believe VBA will be necessary.

Comment: Are you open for an Excel formula? :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use VBA (`Interior.ColorIndex`) in a formula which is why you receive the error.

It is not possible to do this without VBA.

```
Function YellowIt(rng As Range) As Boolean
    If rng.Interior.ColorIndex = 6 Then
        YellowIt = True
    Else
        YellowIt = False
    End If
End Function
```

However, I do not recommend this: it is not how user-defined VBA functions (UDFs) are intended to be used. They should reflect the behaviour of Excel functions, which cannot read the colour-formatting of a cell. (This function may not work in a future version of Excel.)

It is far better that you base a formula on the **original condition** (decision) that makes the cell yellow in the first place. Or, alternatively, run a Sub procedure to fill in the True or False values (although, of course, these values will no longer be linked to the original cell's formatting).

Comment: So if I wanted to use this in a cell, would I do something like this? =IF(YellowIt(A5) = True,"True","False")?

Comment: You would write `=YellowIt(A1)`.. if you choose to ignore my advice.

Comment: The formula-version in the prior comment would change the Boolean results to the strings "True" and "False". In which case, you might as well change the return values (in my function) to `As String` and "True" and "False".

Comment: But if I wanted to use this as a conditional statement in an IF function, could I say =IF(YellowIt(A5)=True,Sum(A6:A7),0)?

Comment: It's still returning #NAME?. I tried changing it to a string and just have it return "True" or "False", but it's giving me the same thing.

Comment: And regarding the advice of putting this in the original condition, there is no condition. This is a way that we can manually change the hilighted color and change the condition of the formula.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010. If you copy and paste the entire function into a Standard Module it will work. If not, there must be something else wrong. In which case try it in a new, blank, workbook.

Comment: Magically, it just worked. I made absolutely no change and it suddenly decided to work. Curious. Anyway, thanks for your help, it was invaluable!

Comment: FYI: It is possible to achieve it with Excel Formula

Comment: Sure. See this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887257/how-to-count-up-text-of-a-different-font-colour-in-excel). Here I am determining the Font Color. Similarly you can do it for cell's interior color. The `type_num` for interior color becomes 63 if I am not wrong. If I remember correctly, I answered a question for interior color as well... Now I don't remember which forum it was though :)

Comment: I couldn't find my post but I found JKP has also covered it [HERE](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/excelnames08.asp) And yes it is 63 :p

Comment: @SiddharthRout Interesting that this is possible, +1 thank you. But I think I'll stick with my original advice. Personally, I'd rather not use a formula (or xl4Macro). Others can ;)

Comment: vba over formula or formulas over vba is definitely a personal choice :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe there's any way to get a cell's color from a formula.  The closest you can get is the `CELL` formula, but (at least as of Excel 2003), it doesn't return the cell's color.

It would be pretty easy to implement with VBA:

```
Public Function myColor(r As Range) As Integer
    myColor = r.Interior.ColorIndex
End Function
```

Then in the worksheet:

```
=mycolor(A1)
```

Comment: I tried this as well and it is still is just returning #NAME?

Comment: It worked for me -- though the cells don't automatically refresh.  If you created the cell formula first, you'd have to go back into it and hit enter again.

Comment: +1 Another way to do it :) And for Automatic Refresh, you can use `Application.Volatile` in your function :)

Answer (score 2):

Although this does not directly address your question, you can actually sort your data by cell colour in Excel (which then makes it pretty easy to label all records with a particular colour in the same way and, hence, condition upon this label).

In Excel 2010, you can do this by going to Data -> Sort -> Sort On "Cell Colour".

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem where I needed to only show a value from another Excel cell if the font was black. I created this function:
`Option Explicit

Function blackFont(r As Range) As Boolean
    If r.Font.Color = 0 Then
        blackFont = True
    Else
        blackFont = False
    End If

End Function
`

In my cell I have this formula:
`=IF(blackFont(Y51),Y51," ")`

This worked well for me to test for a black font and only show the value in the Y51 cell if it had a black font.

Answer (score 0):

The only easy solution that I have applied is to recreate the primary condition that do the highlights as an `IF` condition and use it on the `IF` formula. Something like this. Depending on the highlight condition the formula will change but I think that should be recreated (es. highlight greater than 20).

```
=IF(B3>20,(B3)," ")
```