# Count colored cells with a VBA function and output number of hits?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a simple time schedule sheet that we use to keep track of who is working when. It is simple a set of cells covering 24h, where each cell is representing 15 minutes.

There all kan mark when they have worked during the day by just fillng the cells with "their" color.

We have up to four ppl working every day, and I wan't to have an automatic summary of the number of hour they've worked everyday. Right now I have a separate column for each emplyee and besid every day, where I manually fill in the time, but I would like to have this done automatically whenever day fill in their color.

Is that even possible? Anyone got any hints on this to help me forward?

Thanks in advance,
Hmb

Comment: It's possible. What have you tried?

Comment: `Count colored cells`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887257/how-to-count-up-text-of-a-different-font-colour-in-excel

Comment: to add to @pnuts comment, you could then use the initials in formulas to perform calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the link to the other thread here at stackoverflow, must have missed it when I tried to look for an answer.

I also found a premade library with coloring functions and alot of explanations about how to use (and not) color-functions in Excel.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/Colors.aspx

After trying it out I got it all working, and now have a sheet that automatically calculate the times for every person from they colored cells! :)

/Hmb