# Conditional Formatting - Checking Highlighted Cells Excel 2013

Tags: excel

I have 2 columns, A and B. How can I set conditional formatting so that when a cell in column A is highlighted RED, then the corresponding cell automatically updates to "RED" and the cell is highlighted in red? How can I do this without VBA?

Comment: Do you mean when a cell in A is *manually* highlighted in red, or highlighted via its CF rule(s) ?  Is the "corresponding" cell the one in B on the same row ?

Comment: Yes, when a cell in column A is manually highlighted. And then the corresponding cell in B updates automatically.

Comment: I think you're going to need a simple VBA user-defined function for that: regular cell formulas have no way to read a cell's color, with the exception maybe of the old XLM4 Macro function GET.CELL   See: http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=82173

Answer (score 0):

Color is not data. There is no way to do this without VBA. Manually changing a cell's color does not even trigger a VBA event, so even with VBA this will be a challenge.

Color is not data. You can use the Get.Cell technique as discussed in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382561/excel-formula-to-get-cell-color) but it has many flaws.