# Change color to text in Excel 2007

Tags: excel

I have cells with certain color without any text in Excel , now can i change that colors to specific text for Example if the cell color is blue  it needs to be replaced with a text A

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

[Excel formula to get cell color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382561/excel-formula-to-get-cell-color)

Then you can just set a formula to change the cell color text to the appropriate value you need?