# Assigning value to a cell having particular colour in excel

Tags: excel

If I want to assign a value to a cell with a particular colour, how do I do that?

Or better would be to assign a value if the colour comes between a particular range.

For eg, if I assign the colour **R-0, G-196, B-107**, to a cell, I want the cell value to be set to 1. I must be able to add a particular range and get the result of how many cells has this colour.

Or is there a better way to do the above?

Comment: Why does the cell get that colour?  It may be easier to make a formula that uses the why and not the colour itself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382561/excel-formula-to-get-cell-color