# Add row totals if cell is coloured?

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am a novice at Excel, so please bear with me.
I'm trying to do a fortnightly budget.
I have a row of bills to be paid, with a row total at the end.
When a bill is paid I change the colour of the cell.

What I would like to do is have another field at the end of the row to show the total of what has been paid so far based on the colour of the cell.
Is this possible?

If not can anyone recommend a method that would do the same type of thing?

Thank you so much

Tracy

Comment: Are you wanting to count the # of colored cell? If so, this might help: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1155-excel-count-sum-cells-by-color.html

Comment: You cannot reference cell color directly with formulas.  The best would be to have a second column in which you put an `X` or `Paid` or something else.  Then you can use SUMIF() to sum.

Comment: If you do that you could also create a conditional formatting to automatically format the cell with the color once the new column has the prerequisite entry.

Comment: Thanks for the info guys. I figured it wasn't possible but thought I would ask the more knowledgeable people here.

Comment: You'd have to use VBA to achieve this which if you're an Excel novice you're probably not going to want to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid it's not possible to use colour as information to sum cells, please see here for more information.

[Excel formula to get cell color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382561/excel-formula-to-get-cell-color)

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for the info though. Much appreciated :)