# Excel 2016: Format cell based on whether two other cell colors match

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2016

Is it possible to use conditional formatting to color a cell if the colors of two other cells match each other?

Comment: No. But if the two other cells are coloured by conditional formatting too then you could combine the conditional formatting logic of both cells to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24383150/6387479)  where you can get the color code of a cell for use in logical functions. Please note that you are required to save the workbook as macro-enabled as it makes use of the `GET.CELL` function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no formula that can read what color a cell is. Color is not data. don't use cell fill as metadata. Instead, use conditional formatting with logic that can be applied further down the calculation chain.

So, instead of coloring cells yellow manually and then trying to figure out a way to sum all cells where the next one over is yellow, use conditional formatting to set the cell yellow based on a status or value in another, corresponding cell. Then you can use that status or value in the corresponding cell to determine if the cell should be included in a further calculation like a conditional sum.