# Excel: use cell color fill as input for cell formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, autoformatting

I'm using Excel to manage our production schedule. Each cell has a formula that returns a date by which each step in the production process should be complete.

Today, I fill each cell manually to indicate:

```
 Green  = On-schedule
 Yellow = Threat
 Red    = Behind Schedule
```

I am seeking a formula that does the following:

- If cell address is not `Green` AND cell value is less than `TODAY()`, then paint it to `Red`

I also need the ability to override the formula and change cell fill to `Green` once production has caught-up. Simple conditional formatting does not allow manual overriding.

Comment: Maybe you hit the OK button before finishing your question, could you please complete it?

Comment: @sɐunıɔןɐqɐp I've fixed the text because everything after a `<` was invisible.

Comment: Possibly you want to use the cell's color index for your formula. Take a look at this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24382561/excel-formula-to-get-cell-color

Answer (score 1):

What I understand that you are trying to do is to change the row color based on a cell's value in Excel. This is performed by [Conditional Formatting in Excel](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/10/29/excel-change-row-background-color/)

Here I am going to provide you another link also that clearly explain [How To Change Background Color Based On Cell Value In Excel?](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/849-excel-change-background-color-based-on-cell-value.html)

I hope this help you.

Comment: I believe the OP actually is trying to use the color of the cell as input for his formula...