# Pass UDF to each element of an ArrayFormula

Tags: excel, vba

Related to [my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65280997/find-the-most-repeated-value-but-only-in-cells-of-certain-color-in-excel/), im using Chip Pearson's [GetInfo](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/GetInfo.htm)
function, where the arguments are:

> =GetInfo(object, atribute)

However I want to use a Range as input for the `object` parameter and return the corresponding `atribute` for each cell in the input Range when executed as an array formula. Instead, it's returning the `atribute` of the input Range as a whole. For example, if I pass the atribute `Interior.Color` to the range `A2:A5`, it returns 0 since `Interior.Color` is not a valid atribute of a Range object. My expected result is an Array with the `Interior.Color` atribute of each cell in the `A2:A5` range.

I wrote this separate function to handle this, and currently it's working but it's very inefficient since it's looping over every cell in the Range object. Instead I'd like to translate each Cell Item of the Range object to an Array and loop over it.

Original GetInfo function, which I left untouched:

```
Function GetInfo(TopObj As Variant, PropertySpec As Variant) As Variant

Dim PropArr As Variant ' array returned by Split of object tree
Dim ItemSpec As Variant ' item in collection
Dim Obj As Object ' generic Object to hold
                  'the top-level object (ws,wb,range, or app)
Dim Ndx As Long ' loop counter
Dim Pos1 As Integer ' used to find the Item specified in collection objects
Dim Pos2 As Integer ' used to find the Item specified in collection objects
Dim TempObj As Object

'
' split the object/property spec
'
PropArr = Split(PropertySpec, ".")
'
' If Rng is an object, then it must be a Range. That's the only
' type of object you pass from a cell.
'
If IsObject(TopObj) Then
    Set Obj = TopObj
Else
    '
    ' Otherwise, it better be one of the following strings. Else,
    ' blow up the user.
    '
    Select Case UCase(TopObj)
        Case "APP", "APPLICATION"
            Set Obj = Application
        Case "WB", "TWB", "THISWORKBOOK", "WORKBOOK"
            Set Obj = ThisWorkbook
        Case "WS", "TWS", "THISWORKSHEET", "WORKSHEET"
            Set Obj = Application.Caller.Parent
        Case Else
            GetInfo = CVErr(xlErrValue)
    End Select
End If

For Ndx = LBound(PropArr) To UBound(PropArr) - 1
    '
    ' this block of code is for handling items of a collection
    '
    Pos1 = InStr(1, PropArr(Ndx), "(")
    If Pos1 > 0 Then
        '
        ' if we've found the open paren, we're dealing with an
        ' item of a collection. now, find the closing paren.
        '
        Pos2 = InStr(1, PropArr(Ndx), ")")
        ItemSpec = Mid(PropArr(Ndx), Pos1 + 1, Pos2 - Pos1 - 1)
        If IsNumeric(ItemSpec) Then
            ' numeric -- going by index number
            ItemSpec = CLng(ItemSpec)
        Else
            ' string -- going by key name, so get rid of any quotes.
            ItemSpec = Replace(ItemSpec, """", "")
        End If
        '
        ' call the Item method of the collection object.
        '
        Set Obj = CallByName(Obj, Mid(PropArr(Ndx), 1, Pos1 - 1), _
            VbGet, ItemSpec)
    Else
        '
        ' we're not dealing with collections. just get the object.
        '
        Set Obj = CallByName(Obj, PropArr(Ndx), VbGet)
    End If
Next Ndx
'
' get the final property (typically 'name' or 'value' of the object tree)
'
If IsObject(Obj) Then
    GetInfo = CallByName(Obj, PropArr(UBound(PropArr)), VbGet)
End If

End Function
```

my aditional Function:

```
Public Function getArrayInfo(rng As Range, atr As String) As Variant
Dim temp As Excel.Range
Dim out() As Variant
Dim i As Long

ReDim out(1 To rng.Rows.Count, 1 To 1)
Set temp = Intersect(rng, ActiveSheet.UsedRange) 'Intersect UsedRange to help when using whole row/column as input

For i = 1 To temp.Cells.Count 'inefficient loop over a Range object
    out(i, 1) = GetInfo(temp.Cells(i, 1), atr)
Next i

getArrayInfo = out

End Function
```

Attached is an example where I use the `getInfo` function over an array and it returns the parameter `interior.Color` of the whole array, which is undefined and returns 0. to the right, I have my function where I *do* get the expected result, but as I mentioned, runs very slow over large datasets.

[image: example use case]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating an Array from a Range in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37689847/creating-an-array-from-a-range-in-vba)

Comment: No, I already tried something similar. That way each array element contains only the cell values, and I need each array element to contain individual cell objects, because I'm interested in reading the cell properties such as `Interior.Color`, not just the value

Comment: You have to loop over each cell. There's no alternative.

Comment: That's what I feared when I couldn't figure out another solution. So what I'm currently doing is as efficient as it's gonna get?

Comment: I don't know of any other way, so yes.

Comment: You can create an array of ranges, but again that would not be any quicker than iterating the ranges.  When looking at the format of a cell, it requires the range.

Comment: Yeah I figured reading that array could be marginally faster, but that gain would be offset from the computation of looping over the Range to populating the array anyways. Still, apreciate the help!